# How to concatenate different child nodes using xpath

Tags: loops, xpath, concatenation, nodes, difference

I have an EDIFACT file which has, among others, three fields:

```
- Value
- Exam
- Numb
```

They are under a loop and can have ‘n’ values. An example below where n=4:

```
Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4
Exam 1, Exam 2, Exam 3, Exam 4
Numb 1, Numb 2, Numb 3, Numb 4
```

I would like to concatenate `Value`, `Exam`, `Numb`.
If I am doing a regular concat, the string would look like

```
Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4, Exam 1, Exam 2, Exam 3, Exam 4, Numb 1, Numb 2, Numb 3, Numb 4
```

However, I want to have them displayed as this:

```
Value 1, Exam 1, Numb 1, Value 2, Exam 2, Numb 2 Value 3, Exam 3, Numb 3, Value 4, Exam 4, Numb 4.
```

I tried this:

`concat(string-join(Value, ' '), '', string-join(Exam, ' '), '', string-join(Numb, ' '))`

and the output was:

```
Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 4, Exam 1, Exam 2, Exam 3, Exam 4, Numb 1, Numb 2, Numb 3, Numb 4
```

Also tried the below and no output was generated

```
string-join(Value/concat(Exam, ' ',Numb, ' '), '')

string-join(Value/string-join(Exam | Numb, ''), '')
```

Can you please advise how can I used XPATH to achieve this? Any other method will do as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this `xpath` `axes`.

```
concat(string-join(value, ' '), '', string-join(value[descendant-or-self::exam], ' '), '', string-join(value[descendant-or-self::numb], ' '))
```